# Angular dynamic page

Tags: angular, multidimensional-array, dynamic

I would like to have some recommandation regarding a project I want to create.
I have an Angular page with some controls and I need to give to my customers the ability software side to customize the page.

Here an example:
 `<div>`
    `<label>Title: </label>`
    `<text-control id="title" name="title" />`
  `</div>`
  `<div>`
    `<label>Surname: </label>`
    `<text-control id="surname" name="surname" />`
  `</div>`
  `<div>`
    `<label>Name: </label>`
    `<text-control id="name" name="name" />`
  `</div>`

Typical requests I need to solve is:

1. hide some items
2. require mandatoriness of some fields
3. manage different order of items

Ideally the best solution is give the ability to the customer to write is own HTML template inside a configuration area of the software (but I'm open to total different solution if this is impossible to achieve). E.g. final result could be:

`<div>`
    `<label>Name: </label>`
    `<text-control required id="name" name="name" />`
  `</div>`
  `<div>`
    `<label>Surname: </label>`
    `<text-control id="surname" name="surname" />`
  `</div>`

As you understand I cannot compile it, it has to be a dynamic solution where customer can make runtime the choice of how the software will looks like.

Actually I have not idea where to start.

Any ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to build a page where users can select different control fields, drag and drop them, and add options such as name, placeholder, and validation rules like required, min, and max. It should be similar to [this](https://formbuilder.online/) or [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ybLbXrNB1rY).

After the user clicks `save` button, you will transform it to JSON schema. You can then use that JSON schema to build an [Angular dynamic form](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form).